# How can I fetch data from shapes and diagrams of a word document using gembox document bundle?

Tags: ms-word, fetch, shapes, diagrams, gembox-document

My word file contains shapes and diagrams with data strings in them. Need to fetch those data. Gembox Document provides examples of fetching data from header footer and basic paragraph structure.

Answer (score 1):

Without checking your file no one can say for sure, nevertheless a shape that contains a text inside of it should be a [TextBox element](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/help/html/T_GemBox_Document_TextBox.htm).
You can fetch the `TextBox` text like the following:

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("Sample.docx");

foreach (TextBox textBox in document.GetChildElements(true, ElementType.TextBox))
{
    string text = textBox.Content.ToString();
    // ...
}
```